# Propane BBQ flame too high

Tags: propane

when I turn up the flame on my propane bbq, I start to get a hissing sound, like the pressure is too high. This started happening after cleaning around the burner. It happens on both sides so it’s not the knobs. Is it possible the regulator is busted?  I’ve taken it off the tank and put back on but same result. Here is a video of the problem: https://share.icloud.com/photos/0RYk9cj1pOW11b082YBLHTqPg

Comment: what happens when you turn down the valve on the tank?

Comment: @jsotola The valve on a propane tank won't cause this, LPG is at 100-200 psi in the tank, and the regulator typically reduces that to less than 1 psi. Opening the valve a tiny amount vs all the way doesn't matter as long as the tank isn't 99% empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the gas flow is too high to maintain a flame, and it seems like the pressure is too high, then yes your regulator is bad.

I didn't watch your link since I'm on mobile, but some amount of hissing is normal if it seems like it's running normally.

Comment: I watched it, it's a high-pressure jet flame that is absolutely abnormal. I agree, failed regulator.

Comment: I changed the regulator and it’s back to normal. Thanks for the help!